# What units are used in GRASS Rasterize?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, rasterization

What units are used in **GDAL Proximity** or **GRASS Rasterize?** 
- 'new size' parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [GDAL Proximity page](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_proximity.html):

> **-distunits PIXEL/GEO:**
>
> Indicate whether distances generated should be in **pixel or
>   georeferenced coordinates** (default PIXEL).

So you can specify the distances in pixels or in the unit of the coordinates you used to georeference the raster.